# 500 error when making API token request to cherwell

Tags: c#, rest, api

I'm getting a 500 internal server error when trying to access cherwell REST api via Code trying to return a token to make other calls. I've verified that all the information (username, password, ClientID, and client secret) are all correct. I've also verified the server is up and accepting requests. Something must be wrong with my code. Any help would be great!

```
string token = "";
            string responseBody;
            string serverName = "ql1cwbeta1";

            //initialize web client
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                // pull down parameters for body
                string grantType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["grant_type"];
                string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_id"];
                string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
                string authMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth_mode"];

                //add parameters in headers
                webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                // adding parameters in body
                NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"grant_type", grantType},
                    {"client_id", clientId},
                    {"username", username},
                    {"password", password},
                    {"auth_mode", authMode}
                };

                try
                {
                    byte[] responseBytes = webClient.
                        UploadValues("http://" + serverName + "/CherwellAPI/token?auth_mode=" + authMode + "&api_key=" + clientId, "POST", values);
                    responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    return exception;
                }
```

Comment: Have you checked [other party (Cherwell)]'s API docs?

Comment: yes, unfortunately they recommend and provide all examples and information around swagger code gen, but our version of swagger doesn't allow code generation so it doesn't work that way.

Comment: It seems odd to pass `authMode` (and `clientId`) in both the payload and the querystring. _If you really want to pass it twice, it will need to be url encoded in the querystring._

Comment: if i take it out of the querystring it returns a 400 error. if i take it out of the payload it continues to return 500.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code may help you.

```
public static string TokenRequest()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create HTTP Web Request for the token request
                HttpWebRequest tokenRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Values.TokenURL);


                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&client_id=" + ClientId + "&grant_type=" + GrantType);

                // Set request verb POST, content type and content length (length of data)
                tokenRequest.Method = "POST";
                tokenRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                tokenRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

                // Stream request data
                using (Stream stream = tokenRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                // Get the response and read stream to string
                using (WebResponse response = tokenRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            // responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            return sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Catch error for bad URL (404) or bad request (400) resulting from bad input (username, password, client id, grant type in token request)
                if (ex.Message.Contains("400"))
                {
                    // do something for bad request
                }
                else if (ex.Message.Contains("404"))
                {
                    // do something for not found
                }
                else
                {
                    // unknown error, do something
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // General Exception
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - You can include the client ID as part of the querystring *if all parameters are included in the querystring*, but if you are also sending a payload, then authmode should be the only thing in the querystring.

It will accept all of these parameters as querystrings.

However, you should know that for Cherwell specifically, if you are using LDAP auth / user accounts, you may need to URL encode your username values.

There are certain special characters that will break the auth command. Specifically, including a backslash for a domain can cause issues if it's not escaped with %5C , which I believe can cause a 400 error.

Also a cause of an error can be if you've chosen an authmode that's not enabled for the browser apps in the Security Settings page of the admin console ;)